# Improving div alignment

Tags: css, html, alignment

The goal is to align two divs next to each other.

HTML:

```
<div class="test1>Text 1</div>
<div class="test2>Text 2</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test1 {
    float: left;
}
.test2 {
    float: left;
}
```

It works as long as the browser window is wider than the two divs. The moment the browser window width can no longer accommodate two divs next to each other, test2 is pushed below test1.

How to prevent this behaviour? So they will always be next to each other (if their total width is greater than the browser width, show a horizontal scrolling bar?).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Putting two flexible divs next to each other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571401/putting-two-flexible-divs-next-to-each-other)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap them in a containing div and give that containing div a fixed width in pixels. Once the browser window becomes smaller than that width, it will display the scroll bar.

Answer (score 1):

You should *wrap* those *divs*, and set the wrap `width` equal to the sum of all child's `width`:

See this [Fiddle Example!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/SdBT2/)

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="wrap" class="clearfix">
        <div class="test1 floatL">Div 01</div>
        <div class="test2 floatL">Div 02</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.floatL {
    float: left;
}
.test1 {
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #D9D9D9;
}

.test2 {
    width: 700px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #CCC;
}


/* helpers */
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: '\0020';
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
  zoom: 1;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function() {
    var sum=0;
    $('#wrap > div').each( function(){ sum += $(this).width(); });
    $('#wrap').width( sum );
});
```

What this does is to collect the with of each *first child* of `#wrap` and sum all together setting it to the width of `#wrap`.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a table and place the divs inside them.
This way it won't overflow to next row.

Comment: The whole point of this is to avoid tables. If I wanted  to use them then I could just place the text in adjacent cells.